# Why does my validation not work when I change an input to an anchor?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with a few required fields. It actually works when the code is like this:

```
<input value="Send Message " type="submit">
```

but when CSS is included, it doesn't work. The form is submitted without any validation.

```
<a class="button form-button-submit" >  Send </a>
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: Without code to debug there's not a lot we can do other than guess. Create a JSFiddle to illustrate please.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: I'm just guessing, but different calls to submit probably are submitting your form in different ways, and thus, probably the second method is not passing through the client validation.

Comment: This post needs a [mcve] to assist, as there's way too much missing to tell you what the problem is, specifically, with your validation process (since we can't even see it). That being said, changing an `input` element to an `a` element is **NOT** "including CSS". CSS is CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

With the link button, you are using JavaScript to submit the form.  This may not always cause the browser to validate the data. Instead, use a normal submit button and style it accordingly, like this:

```html
<form action="/somewhere" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a_field" required>
    <button type="submit" class="form-button-submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: H.M - it doesn't work as yet ! still goes to the next page without valdiation

Comment: J.M There is not Js code involved here ! It happens through HTML5 .. Required attribute

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you're not just adding CSS, you're changing the HTML!

Keep the element the same, but apply the classes and you should be alright.

```
<input value="Send Message" type="submit" class="button form-button-submit">
```

Comment: When the class is applied it fails;  <input value= " Send my Feedback !" type="submit" class="button form-button-submit"> ... but work this way without class,  <input value= " Send my Feedback !" type="submit" > .. but I do need the class support..